# mac using date to show seconds has "illegal time format" error

Tags: macos, terminal

I tried the following on mac terminal, and found it has some problem:

```
date –j –f '%d-%b-%Y' "22-Aug-2013" "+%s"
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Could anybody help me to parse this string `22-Aug-2013` and get the epoch seconds?

Comment: that is because `Linux` has a different date command to achieve the same thing, which I did not say in my post.

Comment: In which case it really isn't relevant. Tags should be used in such a way that they either help users of said tag or attract help from users of said tag. Neither use-case scenario applies here. Please remove the `linux` tag. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I removed the tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the wrong character before your option characters `j` and `f` — you’re using an en dash (–,  U+2013) rather than a hyphen (-, U+002D).  Unix tools don't tend to be terribly Unicode savvy when parsing command-line arguments :-)

You may find TextWrangler/BBEdit’s Character Inspector palette useful, or if you're more of an Emacs person, `M-x describe-char`.

Answer (score 4):

I had no issue in OS X 10.8.4:

```
$ date -j -f '%d-%b-%Y' "22-Aug-2013" "+%s"
1377223888

$ date -j -f '%s' 1377223888
Thu Aug 22 21:11:28 CDT 2013
```

Note that it is taking the current time and including it with the specified date.  It would be more accurate to explicitly set the time:

```
$ date -j -f '%d-%b-%Y %T' "22-Aug-2013 00:00:00" "+%s"
1377147600

$ date -j -f '%s' 1377147600
Thu Aug 22 00:00:00 CDT 2013
```

Comment: that is weird. what is the difference between yours and mine?

Comment: @QiangLi I executed the example exactly as you presented it.  What version of OS X are you running?